# The use of gradation

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word to use instead of *gradation* if it's wrong in this context. And should it be *economic* or *economical*?

"Different economic systems have different *gradation* for high, middle and low level salaries."

Comment: Perhaps *tiers*? Or *benchmarks* or *thresholds* perhaps.

Comment: Should it be "low level" or "low-paying?"